# Yii2 global filter/behavior to force user to authenticate first

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

In my Yii2 application I'm trying to force all users to be authenticated. If they're not already authenticated they should be redirected to the login page.

In Yii1 I did this by creating a class that would check if a user was logged in and attaching that class to the `onBeginRequest` behavior in my main config file.

```
// Yii 1
'behaviors' => array(
    'onBeginRequest' => array(
        'class' => 'application.components.RequireLogin',
    )
),
```

How can I get the same behavior in Yii2? I know I can use behavior to do this, but I wan't to add this behavior to my main config file so all requests are first checked for authentication.

The working behaviors method looks like this:

```
// Yii2
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an accesscontrol to the basecontroller?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, so I had to add the following code **below** `'components' => [...]`

```
 'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
            'allow' => true,
        ],
        [

            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Read more about the format: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#configuration-format

Comment: Hint: this code adds an behavior to the application. It doesn't have to be part of components - it must be part of the config itself. So this is why jagsler wrote **below** components, not _in_ components. And `'as someNameHere' => ...` is the syntax for adding behaviors. Look here for [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#configuration-format). I just write this because I have spend some hours finding that out.

Comment: Very nice. It saves my time.

Comment: Another note: you need to have a controller and an action `site/login` because this gets called if the user is not logged in and no rule applies. This can be changed in the configuration (see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html) for more information) if the login action has another name or is another controller.

Comment: If you exclude `error` from the allowed actions it causes a white screen. Previously you could use this to redirect everyone that was not logged in, however, you can no longer redirect 404 errors etc since some updates. I found the current way here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11054#issuecomment-198310042

Comment: @robsch thanks very much! Your comment saved my time!

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually not versed into Yii2 (but very much so into Yii1).

One solution that can be employed in Yii1 and I guess also in Yii2 is having a filter method in a master Controller class. Typically a single controller serves as a master controller. If you don't have one, create it and everyone should extend it. You can implement this probably not as a filter but in other methods of this 'master controller' (init() ?)
If all activity is going through controller class then you're set.