# Yii2 check if user is logged before every page

Tags: authentication, yii2

I am new to Yii2. 
How can i check if **user is logged in or not**?

If user is not logged in then it should redirect to login page. 
Is there any global solution?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25998802/57091)

Comment: @robsch did't worked this

Comment: What problem have you got?

Comment: @robsch it is solved :) thank you..

Answer (score -1):

I set the 'access' behaviors  in all controllers

```php
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

or check the   `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` value

Comment: can you please explain each line of code?

Comment: and i am getting Error (#1)

Comment: This is a tipical way for restrict the access eg in a controller in this case th sample say: this rules are applyed only to `logout` and `signup` . for signup the access is allowe tu guestm for logout the action is allowe only tu authenticated user. For more detail see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html Access Control Filter